# Who is this white-haired woman behind the Punisher?

Tags: marvel, character-identification

I was able to identify most of these Marvel heroes, but who is the woman with white hair behind The Punisher? She is circled with a light blue (red had too little contrast) freehand circle in the top right corner.

[image: Marvel heroes poster]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That would be Black Cat, Marvel's answer to Catwoman. She's a cat burglar who has had a flirtatious relationship with Spider-Man since the mid-1980s. You can read more about her at [the Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.com/universe/Black_Cat_(Felicia_Hardy)#axzz5J74Io9TJ)

[image]

Comment: And, as with Catwoman, she's ranged from being a simple burglar, to a hero, to a crime lord.